# Adding @EnvironmentObject to a view immediately breaks compile

Tags: swiftui

First we have the app file setup like this

```
import SwiftUI
class PromptManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedArtists: Set<String> = Set<String>()
}

@main
struct EnvTestApp: App {
    @StateObject var promptManager: PromptManager = PromptManager()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(promptManager)
        }
    }
}
```

the manager is intended to be accessible by all views of the app.

Then inside our first view, we have one task like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var promptManager: PromptManager
    @State var test:Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("abc") {
            Task {
                await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
                    group.addTask {
                        await doSomeNetwork1()
                        test = false  //<<<<breaks
                    }
                    group.addTask {
                        await doSomeNetwork2()
                        test = false  //<<<<breaks
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we get compile error right away

> Main actor-isolated property 'test' can not be mutated from a Sendable closure

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
 with enough context to understand what you are doing, e.g what is `fetching1` and what it `Manager`, how are they used in your problem code.

Comment: Edited the whole question with complete buildable project

Comment: AFAIK, you should not use property setters from code that is not run on the `Task` isolated code.
You could try using a function: `await setTest(false)` in the `Task{...}`,
 with `func setTest(_ bool: Bool) { test = bool }`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding `@MainActor` to the capture list of your `Task`, to force it to run on the MainActor, e.g.

```
group.addTask { @MainActor in
    await doSomeNetwork1()
    test = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can fix the error by adding a function

```
func changeTest(_ value: Bool) {
    test = value
}
```

and use it

```
group.addTask {
      await doSomeNetwork1()
      await changeTest(false)
}
```

But a better practice is to put all the asynchronous stuff in `PromptManager` and `Publish` the `test` property

Comment: But promptManager is meant to be an app wide data manager, meanwhile test is a local state to ContentView. ContentView wants to fetch some network data, and when that's done, set the test variable so that UI can update. In this case, how should it be architected?

Comment: `ContentView` asks `PromptManager` to fetch the data and `@Publish` the result.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it's best to use `.task(id:)` for your async/await, e.g.

```
@State var isLoading = false
@State var errorMessage = ""

var body: some View {
     Button(isLoading ? "Cancel" : "Load") {
         isLoading.toggle()
     }
     .task(id: isLoading) {
          if !isLoading {
              return
          }
          do {
             try await fetcher.fetchArtists()
             errorMessage = ""
          }
          catch {
              errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
          }
          isLoading = false
     }
```

This way the the async work can also be cancelled.

And your fetcher object would usually look like this:

```
class ArtistFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var artists: [Artist] = []

    func fetch() async throws {
        // on background thread
        let a = try await Api.fetchArtists()

        // or do your task group here

        Task { @MainActor in
            // main thread
            self.artists = a
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your example, how isLoading updated after the network is done?